# Translation Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

> Let $|\psi\rangle \to |\psi'\rangle = \hat{T}(\delta x)|\psi\rangle$ for infinitesimal $\delta x.$ Show that $\langle x \rangle' = \langle x \rangle + \delta x$ and $\langle p_x \rangle' = \langle p_x\rangle.$

I am confused. Why would $\langle x \rangle = \langle x \rangle + \delta x?$
Shouldn't it equal $\langle x \rangle?$ Since, $\langle x\rangle' = \langle \psi'|\hat{x}|\psi'\rangle = \langle \psi'|x\hat{T}(\delta x)|\psi\rangle$ and using $\hat{T}(\delta x) = e^{-i\hat{p}_x\delta x/\hbar}$ then $\langle \psi |\hat{T}^{\dagger}(\delta x)\hat{T}(\delta x)x|\psi\rangle = \langle x\rangle.$

Comment: $[x,T(\delta x)]\neq 0$. Working with an infinitesimal $\delta x$ you can use the taylor expansion to find what the commutation relation is.

Comment: $[x,T(\delta x)] = \delta x T(\delta x) $ but then regarding to $p_x$, will $[p_x, T(\delta x)] = 0$?

Comment: Yes. One way to make sense of it is if you expand the exponential you get $\hat{p}_x$ terms, and $[\hat{p}_x,\hat{p}_x]$=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused. Why would $\langle x \rangle = \langle x \rangle + \delta x$?

Because you acted with the translation operator on the state. This is by definition what we want the translation operator to do. If it doesn't do this then we are in trouble.

> Shouldn't it equal $\langle x \rangle?$

Nope.

> Since, $\langle x\rangle = \langle \psi'|\hat{x}|\psi'\rangle =\langle \psi'|x\hat{T}(\delta x)|\psi\rangle$ 
>   and using
>   $\hat{T}(\delta x) = e^{-i\hat{p}_x\delta x/\hbar}$ then 
>   $\langle \psi|\hat{T}^{\dagger}(\delta x)\hat{T}(\delta x)x|\psi\rangle = \langle{}x\rangle.$

Nope.

$$
T^\dagger x T\neq T^\dagger T x
$$

so
$$
\langle \psi'|x\hat{T}(\delta x)|\psi\rangle
\neq
\langle \psi|\hat{T}^{\dagger}(\delta x)\hat{T}(\delta x)x|\psi\rangle
$$

You should have:
$$
\langle x\rangle = \langle \psi'|\hat{x}|\psi'\rangle =\langle \psi'|x\hat{T}(\delta x)|\psi\rangle= \langle \psi|\hat{T}^\dagger(\delta x)x\hat{T}(\delta x)|\psi\rangle
$$

Then you have to commute $T$ and $x$, and then use the fact that $T^\dagger T=1$.

HINT[!!!]:
$$
[x,p]=i\hbar
$$

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed to understand. Once I receive 15 reps I will make sure to upvote your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Hft, I ran into a problem that is similar to this. It says if we modify the wave equation by a position dependent phase, i.e. $e^{ip_ox/\hbar}$ then $\langle x\rangle = \langle x \rangle$ and $\langle p_x \rangle = \langle p_x \rangle + p_o$, but I am not sure why that is?

Comment: post it as a new question. Add more detail. We can not carry on an extended discussion in the comment area.

Comment: But, from what I can tell the problem is basically the same but with the p *operator* replaced by the x *operator* and the $\delta x$ *number* replaced by the $p_\sigma$ *number*. If that is not clear then post it as a new question.