# Unitary translation in phase space coordinate

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, canonical-conjugation

If we suppose that we can translate one point to another point in phase space $(x,p)$ through the following operators,
$$T(\Delta x) = \exp(-i p~\Delta x ) $$
and
$$T(\Delta p) = \exp(-i x~\Delta p ) ,$$
I want to see if there is any common point between these transformations and canonical transformation?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is - when you write $\exp(-\mathrm{i}p\Delta x)$ as "operators" on the phase space, what exactly do you mean by the exponential, and what do you mean by "is there any common point"?

Comment: Consider that we have a function like $\psi = \psi(x,p) $ and we want to translate this function on phase-space coordinate. If I apply $T(\Delta x)$, then it would be translated for $\Delta x$ in horizontal axis and if I apply $T(\Delta p)$ then it would be translated similarly in p axis. But because x and p are not commuting, according to Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, there would be an extra phase while we're reaching to final point. I want to see that this form of translation can be interpreted by means of canonical transformations?

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. You seem to be mixing up classical and quantum mechanics freely. In quantum mechanics, where $x$ and $p$ do not commute, you can't really have a function $\psi(x,p)$ for that very reason. In classical mechanics, translations in momentum and position directions *do* commute. I'm afraid I'm either misunderstanding something or your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But at least we can have $\psi(x)$ and we can work on it. And I know that when we're talking about commutation of x and p, we're actually are in quantum scope. What I'm trying to know is that we have Poisson-Bracket commutation similar to what we have in quantum mechanic commutation, does it allow us to bring down the question form quantum scope to classical mechanic?

Comment: Related [174203](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174203/translation-operators).

Answer (score 1):

Let us stick to Quantum mechanics, so, then, use *P* and *Q* for operators, and, to avoid confusion, *s=Δx* and *t=Δp* for classical shift parameters.

You then evidently wrote down the (conjugates of) celebrated [*U* and *V* Weyl operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem#Uniqueness_of_representation) (1927), useful in the braiding form of the canonical commutation relations,
$$
e^{itQ} e^{isP} = e^{-i st} e^{isP} e^{itQ}  .
$$

Their actions on functions of *x* are rephase ("clock") and shift,
$$
e^{itQ}\psi(x)=   e^{itx}\psi(x),\qquad  e^{isP}\psi(x)=\psi(x+s),
$$ 
and for *p*,
$$
e^{isP}\phi(p)=   e^{isp}\phi(p),\qquad  e^{itX}\phi(p)=\phi(p-t).
$$

They have particularly handy properties and serve as a bridge to finite dimensional Hilbert spaces (clocks).

I'm not sure how much you'd like to base your classical limit from quantum canonical transformations to classical ones (it is a truly daunting and treacherous area, approached with respect, if not trepidation!) on these; but, *of course*, they are both canonical as they preserve Heisenberg's commutation relation, 
$$
e^{itQ} e^{isP} [Q,P] e^{-isP}e^{-itQ}= [Q,P]=i.
$$

If you really wished to get into quantum canonical transformations in phase space, where angels fear to tread, you may start from [Bracken,   Cassinelli, and Wood, "Quantum symmetries and the Weyl–Wigner product of group representations", *Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General* **36.4** (2003) 1033](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0211001.pdf) and pursue the groaning bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

The connection uses the formalism of Lie transform.  Please refer to the following for additional details:

1. Ernesto Corinadelsi, *Classical Mechanics*, Chap. 9
2. Alex J. Dragt, *Lectures on non-linear orbit dynamics*

I will basically reproduce the derivation of Corinadelsi with some minor modifications. The method similar in spirit to the interaction picture of quantum mechanics.

Suppose $H(q,p)$ is the Hamiltonian of a natural system, 
and does not depend explicitly on $t$.  Therefore, $H(q(t),p(t))=H(q_0,p_0)$ with $q_0=q(0)$ and
$p_0=p(0)$, the energy the same at any point in the motion, and
in particular is the same as the energy at the start of the motion.

The time-evolution of *any* function $f$ is then given by
$$
\frac{df}{dt}=\{f,H\} 
$$ 
We seek to write
$$
f(q(t),p(t))=e^{t \Omega}f(q_0,p_0)
$$
for some operator $\Omega$ with the exponential formally
defined using the series
$e^{t \Omega}:=\sum_k \frac{t^k\Omega^k}{k!}$.
For notational convenience, set
$$
z(t)=(q(t),p(t)):=z\qquad z(0)=z_0=(q_0,p_0)\, .
$$ 
Now, $z(t)$ are canonical variables, just like $z_0$, so that, 
in the Poisson bracket, we can use $\{f,H\}_{z_0}$.

In particular, 
$$
\frac{df(z)}{dt}=\{f(z(z_0,t),H(z_0)\}_{z_0}
$$
always, and certainly
$$ 
\frac{df(z)}{dt}\Bigl\vert_{t=0}=\{f(z(z_0,t),H(z_0)\}_{z_0}\Bigl\vert_{t=0}=\{f(z_0),H(z_0)\}_{z_0}\, .
$$ 
Define
$$ 
\Omega f(z_0):= \frac{df(z)}{dt}\Bigl\vert_{t=0}=
\{f(z_0),H(z_0)\}_{z_0}\, .
$$ 
Clearly, 
$$ 
\Omega^2 f(z_0)=\Omega(\Omega f(z_0))=\frac{d^2 f}{dt^2}
\Bigl\vert_{t=0}=\{\{f(z_0),H_0\},H_0\}_{z_0}
$$ 
etc.  In particular, assuming $f(z(t))$ is smooth, it has a series
expansion
\begin{align}  
f(z(t))&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\left(\frac{d^n f(z(t))}{dt^n}
\right)_{t=0}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\Omega^n f(z_0)=e^{t\Omega}f(z_0)
\end{align} 
Now, $\Omega$ is determined only by $H$. For instance, if your Hamiltonian is
$H=p$, the generator of translations, we have, for any function:
$$
\Omega f(z_0)=\{f(z_0),H(z_0)\}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_0}
\frac{\partial p_0}{\partial p_0}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_0}
\frac{\partial p_0}{\partial q_0}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_0}
$$ 
and, since the function $f$ is arbitrary, we find
$$
\Omega=\frac{\partial }{\partial q_0}\, ,\qquad
e^{t\alpha\Omega}f(q_0,p_0)=f(q_0+\alpha t,p_0)\, ,
$$
which can easily be verified using any $q_0^k$.
If, on the other hand, $H=q$, then one find
$$
\Omega=-\frac{\partial }{\partial p_0}\, .
$$